# StreamReader - Конструктор класса с аргументом переменной

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Создаю консольное приложение, которое при изменении переменной должно сохранять данные в новый файл. Конструктор класса:

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\New\1.txt");
```

**Вопрос**: Как реализовать передачу переменной во входящие параметры? Как я вижу решение, которое не подходит:

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\New\{0}.txt", count); // Error
```

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Откуда на вопросе взялась метка c#-faq? Если бы подобные вопросы и правда задавались часто - вы бы уже нашли ответ не задавая вопрос...

Comment: @PavelMayorov обсуждение встроенной библиотеки разве не faq?

Comment: Нет. FAQ - это часто задаваемые вопросы. Ваш вопрос не частый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(string.Format(@"D\New\{0}.txt", count));
```

Или так:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader($@"D\New\{count}.txt");
```

И вы, кажется, потеряли двоеточие по дороге.

Comment: Спасибо, подошло

Comment: @Rifter: Пожалуйста!